# Select parent ListBoxItem upon CheckBox interaction

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Simple question though. I have a WPF application (.NET 4.0). There is a listbox which contains a number of userpanels. Each of these userpanels contains a checkbox.

When running you can click any portion of the userpanel except the checkbox itself and the listbox will select that row (which is indicated visually by the background changing in this simple case). If you check the box the row is not selected.

Requirement:
If you check the checkbox, this should count as selecting the row.

Checkbox Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CheckboxClickExample.CheckboxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="189" d:DesignWidth="221">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="checkBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="CheckboxClickExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:checkboxsample="clr-namespace:CheckboxClickExample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListBox>        
        <checkboxsample:CheckboxControl/>
        <checkboxsample:CheckboxControl/>
        <checkboxsample:CheckboxControl/>
        <checkboxsample:CheckboxControl/>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle this in your `UserControl` code behind:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = sender as DependencyObject;

        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is Selector)
                break;

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        if (parent != null)
            ((Selector) parent).SelectedItem = this;
    }
```

And then use the handler in your `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
          Height="16"
          Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="10,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to use code behind, the best I think you can do is to package the existing solution as an attached behaviour. This has the benefit that you only have to write the code once, and that the property can be set on any button even if it is not part of a `UserControl`.

For example:

```
public static class ButtonClickHelper
{
    public static void SetEnableSelectionOnClick(ButtonBase button, bool value)
    {
        button.SetValue(EnableSelectionOnClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetEnableSelectionOnClick(ButtonBase button)
    {
        return (bool) button.GetValue(EnableSelectionOnClickProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableSelectionOnClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnableSelectionOnClick", typeof (bool), typeof (ButtonClickHelper),
                                            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnEnableSelectionOnClickPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnEnableSelectionOnClickPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
                                                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is ButtonBase))
            return;

        var button = (ButtonBase) d;
        if ((bool) e.NewValue)
        {
            button.Click += OnButtonClick;
        }
        else
        {
            button.Click -= OnButtonClick;
        }
    }

    private static void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = sender as DependencyObject;
        var ancestors = new List<DependencyObject>();

        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is Selector)
                break;

            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            ancestors.Add(parent);
        }

        if (parent != null)
        {
            var selector = (Selector) parent;
            var itemToSelect = ancestors.Where(i => selector.Items.Contains(i)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (itemToSelect != null)
                ((Selector) parent).SelectedItem = itemToSelect;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in your XAML by just setting the `EnableSelectionOnClick` dependency property:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
          Height="16"
          l:ButtonClickHelper.EnableSelectionOnClick="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="10,10,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Hope this helps!